# Python: Focus on ttk.Notebook tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, focus, ttk

I haven't figured out how to set the focus on a specific tab of a ttk.Notebook. focus_set does not work. Is there any possibility?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem.  What I found is the 'select' method for notebooks (ttk.Notebook.select(someTabFrame)) solves this problem:

```
import ttk, Tkinter

mainWindow = Tkinter.Tk()

mainFrame = Tkinter.Frame(mainWindow, name = 'main-frame')
mainFrame.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH) # fill both sides of the parent

nb = ttk.Notebook(mainFrame, name = 'nb')
nb.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH, padx=2, pady=3) # fill "master" but pad sides

tab1Frame = Tkinter.Frame(nb, name = 'tab1')
Tkinter.Label(tab1Frame, text = 'this is tab 1').pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
nb.add(tab1Frame, text = 'tab 1')

tab2Frame = Tkinter.Frame(nb, name = 'tab2')
Tkinter.Label(tab2Frame, text = 'this is tab 2').pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
nb.add(tab2Frame, text = 'tab 2')

nb.select(tab2Frame) # <-- here's what you're looking for

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

python docs for ttk.Notebook:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Notebook

I also used this blog post as a model for my code:
http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/06/blog-post.html

Answer (score 0):

This code based on **wordsforthewise**'s answer to this question. Here you can find example of using *select* as get and set function, it shown by button that switch between 2 tabs.

small improvement:

```
import ttk, Tkinter
from pango import Weight
from Tkinter import Button


tab2Frame = None
tab1Frame = None

def switchTab():
    if nb.select()[-1] == "1":
        nb.select(tab2Frame)
    elif nb.select()[-1] == "2":
        nb.select(tab1Frame)

mainWindow = Tkinter.Tk()

mainWindow.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (200, 200))
mainFrame = Tkinter.Frame(mainWindow, name = 'main-frame')
mainFrame.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH) # fill both sides of the parent

button = Button(mainWindow, text = "Switch", command = switchTab)
button.configure(width = 15, activebackground = "#6f6Fff")
button.pack()

nb = ttk.Notebook(mainFrame, name = 'nb')
nb.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH, padx=2, pady=3) # fill "master" but pad sides

tab1Frame = Tkinter.Frame(nb, name = 'tab1')
Tkinter.Label(tab1Frame, text = 'this is tab 1').pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
nb.add(tab1Frame, text = 'tab 1')

tab2Frame = Tkinter.Frame(nb, name = 'tab2')
Tkinter.Label(tab2Frame, text = 'this is tab 2').pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
nb.add(tab2Frame, text = 'tab 2')

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: You wrote "small improvement". Small improvement to what? Can you explain the improvement so people don't have to compare your solution line-by-line to whatever it is an improvement of?

Comment: Yeah, if it's a small improvement, probably a better idea to just edit my post

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I didn't see your  comment somehow. Sorry guys, I can't remember now. I'll try to come back to in later.

Comment: I know this is an old post but `nb.select()[-1] ` for me returns `e` for all tabs. Just thought I would point that out as it appears to not return index or numbers.